# javascript array - accessing json type of objects

Tags: javascript

The code:

---

```
function getDummyDetails(){
 var userDetailsMap = [];
 userDetailsMap.push({key:'APPCODE', value:'41'});
 userDetailsMap.push({key:'WORKERNUMBER', value:'1234567'});
 userDetailsMap.push({key:'ACCOUNTID', value:'DEVELOP'});
 userDetailsMap.push({key:'NAMEFIRST', value:'John'});
 userDetailsMap.push({key:'NAMELAST', value:'Developer'});

return userDetailsMap;
```

}

```
 function someOtherFunction () {

var userDetails = getDummyDetails();  
document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML = "User Name: " + userDetails[3].value + ", " + userDetails[4].value;
```

}

---

Here, it works fine but I can not use the array index here like userDetails[3].value. I was trying to do something like this

```
 userDetails["APPCODE"].value; // just a pseudo code
```

How can I index this array with that string values but not an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create an object instead of an array. That way you'll be able to access it via its key:

```
function getDummyDetails() {
    return {
        'APPCODE':'41',
        'WORKERNUMBER':'1234567',
        'ACCOUNTID':'DEVELOP',
        'NAMEFIRST':'John',
        'NAMELAST':'Developer'
    };
}

function someOtherFunction () {
    var userDetails = getDummyDetails();  
    userDetails["APPCODE"] // 41 - use it however you want...
}
```

Comment: ohh I could do that but isn't there a way to do this userDetails["APPCODE"].value; without touching the function getDummyDetails()

Comment: Yup, this is how it should be. Objects can be indexed by strings like that.

Comment: this works fine, thanks. But, if I keep the function getDummyDetails() as it is, I mean the   valuesuserDetailsMap.push({key:'APPCODE', value:'41'}); BUT NOT as you have like 'APPCODE':'41' then is there any way to access the key APPCODE? thanks

Comment: @jeewan - Not without looping through the array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object, not an array:

```
var userDetailsMap = {
  APPCODE:41
}

var value = userDetailsMap["APPCODE"];//value now = 41
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your structure, you can iterate over your array:

```
for (var i = 0, len = userDetailsMap.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (userDetailsMap[i].key == 'APPCODE') {
    var val = userDetailsMap[i].value;
    // do something with the value here
  } 
}
```

Comment: thanks dude, but I am not looping through all objects here, just need few of them. For now, I just wanted the "APPCODE" here. I am trying now, lets see how am I gonna end up :-)